# Any way to define domain name in login form so that lastpass can autofill it?

Tags: html, ios, authentication, ionic-framework, lastpass

I am trying to figure out why lastpass works with my login password field but not with username

I have a standard ionic/angular app with a regular form. Lastpass only works for the password field, it correctly identifies the domain that I need for my app and prefills password correctly.

However I can't figure out how to do the same for username field, here's a screenshot of how it works for password, but doesn't work like this for username:

[image: lastpass for password]

In that screenshot you see that "Passwords" is clickable above keyboard which invokes LastPass app.

```html
    <form [formGroup]="loginFormGroup">
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-item color="none">
                        <ion-label position="floating">
                            Username or email
                            <span *ngIf="username.hasError('required') && username.touched">
                                field is required
                            </span>
                        </ion-label>
                        <ion-input
                            lines="full" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding"
                            type="text"
                            formControlName="username"
                            autocomplete="username"
                        ></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-item color="none">
                        <ion-label position="floating">
                            Password
                            <span *ngIf="password.hasError('required') && password.touched">
                                is required
                            </span>
                        </ion-label>
                        <ion-input
                            lines="full"
                            class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding"
                            type="password"
                            formControlName="password"
                            autocomplete="current-password"
                        ></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button
                        type="submit"
                        (click)="login()"
                        expand="block"
                        [disabled]="!loginFormGroup.valid"
                        fill="outline"
                    >
                        <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
                        Login
                    </ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

To get iOS' Keychain Password Auto-Fill working for a specific domain in your app, you're supposed to configure an "App Associated Domain".
I'm almost certain this also works for your Lastpass app, since iOS itself forwards you to that app.

To get App Associated Domain's set up in your Xcode project / app, you're supposed to:

- Add the "App Associated Domain" entitlement to your AppID on developer.apple.com
- In your Xcode project settings, enable the associated domains switch
- In the same view, add an associated domain (and port)
- On your webserver you chose in the last step, add a file in the root directory: `apple-app-site-association`
- Add the following contents to that JSON file:

```
{
   "webcredentials": {
       "apps": [ "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.DemoApp" ]
    }
}
```

- Change `D3KQX62K1A` to your Team ID, `com.example.DemoApp` to your bundle ID.

That should do the trick! Passwords will now suggest for that site, since you've linked your app to your site, and vice-versa.

Please see this link for more information:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains

For more information on this subject, see this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look at this.

Comment: How about the native app? Password autofill never work for me.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I have configured everything correctly (as deep linking does seem to work), but my password managers will never recognize the domain.

Answer (score 1):

The username field not being populated by the password managers is a different problem than the password managers not finding the correct password. To fix the auto fill issue, you will have to remove the ion-item wrapping your ion-inputs. Not sure why this fixes the problem but it should in your case since you already have the correct autocomplete attributes.